# How to deal with a variable that is dependent on another variable, for example, demand and price in in Gurobi python interface

Tags: python, gurobi

I am writing an optimisation model that maximises the profit of an airline.

1. This **Profit = Revenue - cost + governemnt_subsidies**
2. I am calculating **Revenue** as **Demand*ticket_price**

The price is a decision variable which airlines can choose and this affects the demand, which I am taking as a decision variable too.

How can I best express this demand-price relationship, should it be a function or a constraint. 
Also, my objective function looks quadratic in the price, do you know of a way of explicitly declaring this objective function?

I am using gurobypy- the Gurobi python interface. Below is a minimum example of what I have done so far--I have not included the governemnt_subsidies because it is not needed for the question.

```py
#--------------------------------
#input data
#--------------------------------
# A list of regions. set R
regions = ["Region_1", "Region_2"]
# A list of airports involved in the auction. set I
airports = ["A", "B"]
# A list of routes R
routes = ["A-B-ARN", "A-ARN", "B-ARN"]
Cost_bh = {
    "A-B-ARN" : 726,
     "A-ARN" : 1116,
     "B-ARN" : 1473
 }

#parameter variables
incidence_matrix_G = dict({
    ("A-B-ARN","A") : 1,
    ("A-B-ARN", "B") : 1,
    ("A-ARN","A" ) : 1,
    ("A-ARN", "B") : 0,
    ("B-ARN","A" ) : 0,
    ("B-ARN", "B") : 1
 })

route_bh = {
     "A-B-ARN" : 2.44,
     "A-ARN" : 1.41,
     "B-ARN" : 1.71
 }

route_maxflights = {
     "A-B-ARN" : 18,
     "A-ARN" : 12,
     "B-ARN" : 12
 }
route_maxprice = {
     "A" : 1300,
     "B" : 1000
 }

catchment = {
     "A-B-ARN" :  283475 ,
     "A-ARN" :  283475 ,
     "B-ARN" :  556465 
 }
#--------------------------------
# Create a new model
#--------------------------------
model = Model("Airline Profit")

#variables
price = {} # the prices an airline is charging per route, and airport
Demand= {} # the price responsive demand an airline gets per route and airport

#Define variables

# define price per route per airport
for route in routes:
    for airport in airports:
        price[route, airport] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS,
                                              name="price_{}_{}".format(route, airport))
# define demand per route per airport, based on the price
for route in routes:
    for airport in airports:
        Demand[route, airport] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS,
                                             name="Demand_{}_{}".format(route, airport))
m.update()

#AK add constraints 
for route in routes:
    for airport in airports:
        model.addConstrs(Demand[route, airport] =  np.exp(0.005 + (1.5434*np.log(catchment[route]))-(0.6774*np.log(route_bh[route]))-(1.8963*np.log(price[route, airport])))

model.addConstrs((price[route, airport]  <= route_maxprice[airport] for route in routes for airport in airports), "price_cap")

# Set objective function components
#AK the revenue for the airline
obj_revenue = quicksum(incidence_matrix_G[route, airport]*Demand[route, airport]*price[route, airport]*route_maxflights[route] for route in routes for airport in airports)

#The total operation cost; cost_bh is aircraft and route
# cost_bh is precomputes for a given route based on the used aircraft
obj_cost_operation = quicksum(Cost_bh[route]*route_bh[route]*route_maxflights[route] for route in routes)

Obj_airline = obj_revenue - 2*obj_cost_operation
model.setObjective(Obj_airline, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

I am currently getting some results but I know that they are not correct because when I do `print(Demand.values())`, I get:

```
dict_values([<gurobi.LinExpr: 18.777961108358838 + -1.8963 price_A-B-ARN_A>, <gurobi.LinExpr: 18.777961108358838 + -1.8963 price_A-B-ARN_B>, <gurobi.LinExpr: 19.14945291443028 + -1.8963 price_A-ARN_A>, <gurobi.LinExpr: 19.14945291443028 + -1.8963 price_A-ARN_B>, <gurobi.LinExpr: 20.05977292744191 + -1.8963 price_B-ARN_A>, <gurobi.LinExpr: 20.05977292744191 + -1.8963 price_B-ARN_B>])
```

My view is that if this was working, I would be getting actual values instead of linear expressions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As it currently stands, you're overwriting the Demand variables (by linear expressions, not constraints). You can model dependencies between decision variables using constraints. Also, you use `m` instead of `model` once in your posted code.

Comment: Thank you @snwflk, I have edited the typo and consistently used ` model`. Also with this correction, I realised that Gurobi cannot under work with the log-log dependency between demand and price. I think that my best alternatives here are to have a linear depency between demand and price or to precompute demand based on a discrete price scale, or to use a non-linear solver. I am currently working with the first two.